# how to the reset value of a textview automatically when time becomes 23:59:59

Tags: android

I am making an app for managing expense.

I take all the information about today's expenses in an `Expense Activity`.

I want to add all of the expenses that happened today and display them in the summary, which is in the `main activity` in **today's expense** `textview`.

But this `textview` should automatically become zero when the user opens the app the next day, meaning the `textview` should be reset to zero at `23:59:59pm` today.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your question.  Could you post a minimal piece of the code that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Did you use an alarm to trigger a broadcast, for example, to update the textview?

Answer (score 1):

You can remember on which day the activity was resumed (eg. with `Calendar.get(DAY_OF_YEAR)`), and when it is different the next time the activity is resumed, reset the text view.

If you need to update it even when the activity is in front, you can use [alarm](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Answer (score 0):

Call a service that keeping track the current time of the device. and when the time is 23:59:59pm just change the textview.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable and save to any internal or external storage.

Run a service and when time finished set this saved variable to zero. And when your activity launches read the value of this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Register an Alarm for Updating/refreshing the UI and a Updating the TODAY_DATE of your application.
The TODAY_DATE should get stored in the SharedPreferences.
So you can calculate the summary for yesterdays expenses and create an empty "Today's  Expenses"

For using Shared preferences:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

For Updating the Shared preferences and the UI/Activity:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html